# Validate select options inside ng-repeat table

Tags: angularjs

I would like to validate or check my select array option inside ng-repeat table if all select option is empty. Then, let say if 2 select option has a value how to get those value. Thanks in advance and really appreciate your help.

html

```
<button type="button" ng-click="checkSelect()">Check</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="getvalue()">get</button>
<table><tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
<td>
    <select ng-model="person.numPerson[$index]" ng-options="num for num in [] | range:5">
        <option value="">0</option>
    </select>
</td></tr></table>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){

        //for validation
        $scope.checkSelect = function () {
        }

        //get all selected select value
        $scope.getvalue = function () {
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your checkSelect function with below

```
//for validation
$scope.checkSelect = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.person.numPerson, function(value, key) {
        if(value == ''){
            //Show alert or maintain a flag to show error to users
            //perform actions 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: but select option not updating when selecting value not empty to empty and vice versa.

Comment: sorry @Rye i am not getting what you saying. can you please expalin a bit more.

Comment: to simplified my question. how to count all values not empty using that code.

Comment: If you will look at the code you will found that we having loop for all the values of the ARRAY. so you can add a check for empty value and increase a counter in that check

Comment: You are welcome , I would be please if you can vote up this. I can have some point hope you will not mind

Answer (score 0):

You can get these selected options via model collection. Say for example:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="person.numPerson[$index]" ng-options="num for num in [] | range:5">
                <option value="">0</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{person.numPerson}}
```

The last line will print all option with the selected option. AngularJS is two binding so you can get these result into a model collection.

If this is not like your desired output, provide some more information, we will conclude it together. :)

Comment: Yes. thanks but how to validate first into the controller if all select value is empty